# re_ocject_recorder no point cloud found

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am trying to record objects with a kinect using ar_bounding_box and re_object_recorder. I installed them via roboearth stack (with svn up -r2047). I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with ROS electric.

Here is what I did:

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
roslaunch ar_bounding_box ar_kinect.launch 
rosrun re_object_recorder record_gui
```

I set the registered_depth param true in device.launch, which is included by openni.launch.

Everything seems to run fine, but the the resulting_pcl topic stays empty.
[image description http://imageshack.us/a/img221/6375/nopointcloud.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img221/6375/nopointcloud.png)
[image description http://imageshack.us/a/img21/4997/objectpointcloud.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img21/4997/objectpointcloud.png)

The only PointCloud2 topic, that's filled, is the /camera/depth_registered/points
[image description http://imageshack.us/a/img4/6539/cameradepthregisteredpo.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img4/6539/cameradepthregisteredpo.png)

But I also can't show this Point Cloud in rviz:
[image description http://imageshack.us/a/img341/6861/rvizjpg.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img341/6861/rvizjpg.png)

[image description http://imageshack.us/a/img839/4711/rxgraph.png](http://imageshack.us/a/img839/4711/rxgraph.png)

What am i doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55860/re_ocject_recorder-no-point-cloud-found/) by [boFFeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/3540/boffel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its probably the OpenNi bug: http://answers.ros.org/question/55513

---

Originally posted by [stfn](https://answers.ros.org/users/3992/stfn/) with karma: 287 on 2013-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0